# Do one-pass compilers still exist?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-optimization

According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_14.html, GCC 2.95 had around 24 different passes, back in the days.

Looking at http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html, LLVM has about a hundred different passes.

Are there any compiler in use today (maybe in embedded environments) that does all of parsing to code generation in one single pass?

Comment: Relax, LLVM does not actually run all the hundreds of its passes for each function or module.

Comment: @SK-logic I'm not actually worried or anything :) This is a question out of sheer curiosity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Tiny C documentation says, it is one pass: http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC30.

Comment: Well, Fabrice Bellard's TCC is an interesting beast, but I am not sure it is used much in the industry - we had a funny time trying to target it because of its partial support for C99, 64-bit architectures and the such. While this is a valid answer I would love to learn about other ones.

Comment: I consider it already as pretty difficult to define a pass: Only count the numbers of the times the sources are read? Only count a compilation step as a pass if an intermediate presentation is written to disk (for me the most usefull definition due to history)? Or each time some intermediate presentation is walked fully? How to count partial walks of an intermediate presentation then? How to count additional compilations due to WPO?

Comment: Yes, that is a legitimate question in itself. It would seem TCC doesn't use any intermediate representation other than value registers. I was mostly thinking of passes as AST transformations (either node swaps in an existing AST or translating an AST to another completely different AST, for example SSA).

Comment: I would say the number of passes in a compiler refers to the number of *complete* traversals of the source program: the input text, the parse tree, the RTL, ... Legend has it that IBM had a compiler project with *N* guys on it and it came in with *N* passes, where *N* was something like 36.

Answer (score 1):

There are several one-pass Cobol compilers. RM-Cobol is certainly one of them, and ACE Cobol too if it still exists anywhere. Cobol is quite a good candidate for a one-pass compiler as it is mostly just hooking runtime library calls together, very little scope for optimization during compilation. I believe ACU-Cobol is also one-pass but I'm open to correction.